# How to avoid overlapping of QListWidget check indicator with the text when scaling them via CSS?

Tags: c++, css, qt

I'm trying to make a list view with enlarged text and check indicator. For this I'm using a style sheet. The problem is that, although the sizes of the text and the indicator have indeed increased, the spacing between them hasn't.

Here's a minimal example of the code:

```
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    const char style[] = R"(
QListWidget::indicator {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
QListWidget {
    font-size: 32px;
}
)";
    app.setStyleSheet(style);

    QListWidget w;
    const auto item = new QListWidgetItem("Some text", &w);
    item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: screenshot]

For reference, here's how it looks without the style, with the correct non-overlapping positioning of the elements:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried playing with `margin` property of `QListWidget::indicator` and `padding` property of `QListWidget`, but this doesn't help, because when e.g. left margin is too negative, the indicator gets clipped.

What is the correct way of setting the expected separation between the indicator and the text?

Comment: It seems an issue with the style and/or OS font scaling. Try setting the font size unit in *points* instead of pixels. Also, what style is using the QApplication? If it's not fusion, try to use it instead and see the result.

Comment: @musicamante The style is Fusion, and with font scaling disabled the problem still remains (with a smaller size of everything, but same overlapping). Setting sizes in points (as `30pt`) scales the text but leaves the indicator at its default small size.

Comment: Did you use 30pt for the font only or for the indicator size too? If so, try leaving the latter in pixels, or do the opposite. It may be a bug, though I cannot reproduce it with your basic example. I'll do further testing later tonight.

Comment: @musicamante I first tried replacing all sizes with 30pt, now have tried your suggestion, which resulted in overlapping. I'm testing on Ubuntu 20.04 with X11 (with Qt 6.4.1 built from source), maybe this depends on platform?.. Though it's kinda strange, since it's just Qt internal functionality.

Comment: On Fedora 38, KDE, X11: Qt 6.2.4 does not reproduce this, however the indicator does not get bigger. Reproducible using Qt 5.15.2, Qt 6.3.2 and later. However, in affected Qt6 versions, if you add `padding-left: 30px` to `::item`, it results in [this](https://ibb.co/CVXTzcP). It looks like 2 items on top of each other, one got the big indicator and the other got the text. But in Qt 5.15.2, [it works with the padding](https://ibb.co/TtnKyfY). So perhaps it's a bug, and it's not possible to use stylesheets to get what you're looking for in Qt6.

Comment: A little nitpicking: the title of your questions says QTreeWidget, but the code uses ``QListWidget``.

Comment: I can confirm this for Qt5 and 6, with the difference that also adding `QListWidget::item { spacing: 0; }` makes it work as expected on Qt5. It seems that the change was introduced in Qt6 indeed, as `CE_ItemViewItem` has a different behavior when an indicator rule is set. I also found some inconsistent behavior with the `QAbstractItemView::item` rule for paddings and margins, so I'm quite sure it's a bug (or, at least, the change wasn't documented appropriately). You may consider submitting a bug report on https://bugreports.qt.io